# Re-format list of dict using python

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary

I dont know how to ask this in a simple way more than:

I have a list of dicts with the same Key but diferent value, like:

```
"data":[
      {
         "path":"messageType",
         "value":"position"
      },
      {
         "path":"fcntup",
         "value":2524
      }, 
      {
         "path":"status/error",
         "value":""
      }]
```

I need to change those keys to the values and create a new dict like:

```
{
"messageType":"position",
"fcntup": "2524",
"status/error": ""
}
```

Any idea who to do this??

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Use dict comprehension like:

```
d = {"data":[
      {
         "path":"messageType",
         "value":"position"
      },
      {
         "path":"fcntup",
         "value":2524
      }, 
      {
         "path":"status/error",
         "value":""
      }] }


d1 = {x['path']: x['value'] for x in d['data']}
print (d1)
{'messageType': 'position', 'fcntup': 2524, 'status/error': ''}
```